# Calculating a bias given the MOM and MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, moment-problem

Question: A company manufactured objects, starting from 1 to N. One of the objects is selected, and serial number is 888. We are asked to find things like the MOM, MLE etc. which I managed without problem.

MOM estimator $\hat{N}$ = $2\bar{X} - 1$, and MLE estimator $\hat{N} = \bar{X}$.

Now, what I want to do is to find the bias. I know that variance of MOM is 4 * Var($\bar{X}$), and variance of MLE is just Var($\bar{X}$). The formula, from what I understand is $[E(\hat{N})-N_o]^2$, but other than that I do not know how to start.

Answer given is that MOM estimator is unbiased, and MLE estimator has bias $\frac{N-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the bias is $E[\hat N - N] = E[\hat N] - N$

Since $E[X]=\frac{N+1}{2}$, you have

- If $\hat N = 2X-1$, then $E[\hat N]=N$ and the bias is $N-N=0$ so the MOM is an unbiased estimator
- If $\hat N = X$, then $E[\hat N]=\frac{N+1}{2}$ and the bias is $\frac{N+1}{2}-N=-\frac{N-1}{2}$ so the MLE is biased downwards

This is the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) with a single sample

Comment: I see...thanks for the detailed explanation. I have 2 questions though. Firstly, does that mean that my formula that I wrote in the question is wrong? Secondly, how do you know that E[X] = $\frac{N + 1}{2}$? If you are using the MOM estimator to derive the E[X], my question would then be: how do you know that E[X] =/= N (as from the MLE estimator)?

Comment: @statsguy21: Given: $N$, you can have $X$ take any of the values $1,2,\ldots,N$ with equal probability and the average of these is $\frac{N+1}{2}$

Comment: @statsguy21: To me, the bias has a direction $\pm$ and is measured in the same units as the original estimate.  So I would say the expected square of the error is  $\text{bias}^2+\text{variance}$.  Others prefer to say it is $\text{bias}+\text{variance}$ and so lose the sign of the bias and change its units

Comment: I got it for the first one regarding the expectation for X, but not really for the second one for the bias. I believe the formula you are talking about (i.e bias$^2$ + variance) is the MSE, right? How does that link to the the difference in formula between your bias and the bias I posted in the question? Thanks!

Comment: @statsguy21 Your $[E(\hat{N})-N_o]^2$ is what I would call the square of the bias

Comment: I see..so in my formula I'm taking the square of the bias whereas in your method you chose not to, right?

Comment: Sign aside, wouldn't this square change the value of the bias?